# UpdatePanel cause error: PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that works fine with multiple a grid and multiple buttons.  The page works fine until I add an asp:UpdatePanel.  Then I get the following message pushing any of my buttons:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format.

There is no javascript on the page just straight html.

Here is the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="TestUpdatePanel.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASCWeb.TestUpdatePanel" %>

<asp:Content ID="mHeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="mBodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Add.png" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

If I take the TextBox out, it works fine.  Nothing is in the code behind.

What would cause this?

Thanks

Comment: Are these ImageButton controls?  Please post code.

Answer (score 0):

As per experience, I only encounter that exception when calling Javascript from codebehind, like when using `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` to call `window.alert()`, for instance. But for this issue, I think this resolves it: http://forums.asp.net/t/1823287.aspx/2/10.